# What does "spin-off" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Below is from "Dare to be Lazy" by Rolang Barthes

> I remember this image: When I was a child, Paris was different. It was before the war. It was hot in the summer, hotter than it is now; at least it seems that way to me. In the evening, you'd often see the concierges ― there were a lot of them, they were an institution ― bring chairs out in the street, and they'd just sit there, doing nothing. It's an image of idleness that has disappeared. In modern Paris, there aren't as many gestures of idleness. The cafe is a kind of laziness, but with **spin-offs**: there are conversations, there is an "appearance" of activity. This is not true idleness.

Hi, what does "spin-off" mean here exactly? I kind of get what it's saying but

I'm not sure which of the two definitions fits in this context: 1)a product that develops from another more important product 2) a programme or other show involving characters from a previous programme

Can you help me interpreting this sentence? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dictionary definitions do not really seem to fit what seems, to me, to mean "benefits".

Comment: Neither of those definitions match what the intention of what Barthes is saying, but they are related. Instead of a "product", think about what's being described here - an activity (or lack of activity). You say you get its meaning already - what do you think it means?

Comment: Looks like a faulty translation.  The original interview (in French) can be found here: [Roland Barthes : osons être paresseux](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/1979/09/17/roland-barthes-osons-etre-paresseux_2783595_1819218.html), but it requires a subscription to *Le Monde*.  Perhaps someone over on the [French Language site](https://french.stackexchange.com/) has a subscription and can help us out.